# Layout with sticky sidebar on the left and scrollable content on the right

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

How do I make a two column layout, where the left column is my menu and is locked (sticky? fixed?) so when you scroll vertically depending on the content height in the right column, the menu stays.

Second thing, I guess i have to use javascript for (vanilla, no jquery) is so make the columns resizable. with the css I would use 'cursor: col-resize' but the JS i have no clue.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 16px;
}

.one {
  background-color: tomato;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.two {
  background-color: #33a8ff;
  height: 5000px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column one">
    <h2> column #1 </h2>
    <p>menu items</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column two">
    <h2>column #2</h2>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`Here is a fiddle:`
https://jsfiddle.net/ojx1g64s/

Comment: Please add the code right in the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: maybe this codepen will help you -> https://codepen.io/pablowbk/pen/bGbxZoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like in my snippet below. Both columns have `height: 100%;`, the right one has `overflow-y: auto` to show a scrollbar only if necessary and scroll the contents inside that column:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #33a8ff;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 16px;
}

.one {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100%;
}

.two {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column one">
    <h2> column #1 </h2>
    <p>menu items</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column two">
    <h2>column #2</h2>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
    <p> Some contents in column 2 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `position:sticky`. But in order to see a difference, set a smaller height on the sidebar.

> Note: `position: sticky` wouldn't work if one of your sidebar's parent, even if it's not a direct one, have its `overflow` set to a different value than the default one, as this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/865) shows.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: tomato;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: min-content;
  flex:1;
}

.content {
  background-color: #33a8ff;
  height: 100vh;
  flex:2;
}

.bottom{
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 16px;
  height: 120vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column sidebar">
    <h2>Sticky Sidebar</h2>
    <p>Menu items.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column content">
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <p> Some scrollable content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <h2>Content On the bottom</h2>
  <p>Some content outside of the block with the sticky sidebar.</p>
</div>
```